# Finding the size of an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, size, sizeof

Normally, I would find the size of the double array by using

```
int size = sizeof(array_name)/sizeof(double)
```

However, I am using the double array named "grades" as a member in a class called "Grades"

```
class Grades{
    private:
        double grades[1024];

    public: Grades(string gradeList);
            Grades();

            int getNumGrades();
            string toString();
};
```

The double array is later filled in the constructor. However, when I do

```
cout << "size = " << (sizeof(grades)/sizeof(double)) << endl;
```

It ALWAYS gives me 1024. This is at the end of the constructor after it has filled some random values. I filled it with 5 values. How can I make this return the number of filled elements?

Comment: You can use `std::vector<double>` and avoid all the headache of keeping track adding and removing from an array of `double`s.

Comment: Always note that `sizeof` is compile time defined (rare exception exists, ignore that). Therefore, the expression will always be `1024` (since compiler has put `1024` there!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have one other member called `elemInArray`, and it could be implemented in this way.

```
class Grades{
    private:
        double grades[1024];
        unsigned int elemInArray;   // Note this

    public: Grades(string gradeList);
            Grades();

            int getNumGrades();
            string toString();
};
```

And whenever you insert the elements or remove elements from that array, you can increment and decrement `elemInArray` to keep track of the number of elements in the array.

Otherwise use STL containers (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Answer (score 1):

It will always return same value what you have specified when creating array. You have to maintain a seperate variable ( let's say "count" ) to keep track of how many elements are there in array.